# Inconsistent minSdkVersion across libraries (Android Studio 0.5.1 + Gradle 0.9)

Tags: android, gradle, android-studio, build-process, google-maps-android-api-2

I have upgraded my Android Studio to the **version 0.5.1** taking care of the [migration](http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/migrating_to_09) process that has to be applied to the build.gradle files into my project and modules.

After having introduced the latest version of the GooglePlayServices(4.2.42)and the [Android-Map-Utils](https://github.com/googlemaps/android-maps-utils), not all the time, I'm facing the following compilation error:

```
Information:[/Users/.../build/exploded-aar/com.google.maps.android/
android-maps-utils/0.3/AndroidManifest.xml:2,
 /Users/.../build/exploded-aar/com.google.android.gms/play-services/4.2.42/
AndroidManifest.xml:3]
 Main manifest has <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion='8'> 
but library uses minSdkVersion='9'
```

Is there anyone who is encountering the same issue?
Any solution?

Many thanks,
Simone

EDIT:

It seems that I'm not the only who has got this problem.

https://github.com/googlemaps/android-maps-utils/issues/60
https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=66109

Answer (score 3):

If you have the problem for another library you can modify this hack: https://gist.github.com/goldierox/9533466

Android bug: https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=66109

EDIT:
The bug has since been fixed.

You can use the new manifest-merger (enabled by default)

http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/user-guide/manifest-merger

To replace the minSdk you would need something like this:

```
<uses-sdk tools:replace="minSdkVersion" android:minSdkVersion="9" android:targetSdkVersion="19"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

According to the docs at http://developer.android.com/google/play-services/setup.html:

> Note: Google Play services 4.0.30 (released November 2013) and newer
>   versions require Android 2.3 or higher. If your app supports Android
>   2.2, you can continue development with the Google Play services SDK, but must instead install Google Play services for Froyo from the SDK
>   Manager.

Android 2.3 is API level 9, so that means that you must declare the minSdkVersion to be 9 or higher. You can do this through your **build.gradle** file:

```
android {
    ...
    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 9
        ...
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Scott, I already knew that and the app is targeting minSdkVersion 9. As you can see from the error is something related to the minSdkVersion of the GooglePlayServices that is currently 9 and the one used by the GoogleMapsUtils that is 8.

Comment: Are you setting it to 9 in the build.gradle file? The build file overrides whatever you put in AndroidManifest.xml.

Comment: The AndroidManifest.xml doesn't contain any sdk version declaration and everything is managed in in the build.gradle as defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 9
        targetSdkVersion 19
        versionCode 9
        versionName "v2.0.0"
    }

Answer (score 1):

If you compile what is on maven with

```
dependencies {
compile 'com.google.maps.android:android-maps-utils:0.3+'
```

}

notice that this version has dependency on play services 3+. I manually cloned git repo and changed that for 4.3.+. Problem solved. According to this https://github.com/googlemaps/android-maps-utils/issues/75 fix will be pushed to maven central, hope soon.